# tengo un error express.static, pero resulta al correr un test

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy probando con jest, un controller en node express. Al correr la prueba me da este error en la línea 2:

[image: Imagen de la consola]

Comment: hola por favor pasa por [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y completa tu pregunta con la informacion nesesaria

Comment: Ten presente que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pon siempre el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Además, modifica el título de tu pregunta para mencionar el error. Lee [ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

por la imagen que agregaste ya tengo algo de contexto, para cargar y configurar correctamente swagger agrega el siguiente codigo

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { load } from 'js-yaml'
import { serve, setup } from 'swagger-ui-express'

const content = load(readFileSync(process.cwd() + '/tu_ruta_a_los/docs.yaml', 'utf-8'))

const router = Router()

router.use('/docs/', serve, setup(content))

export default router
```

luego en tu archivo principal de express; primero, elimina la instruccion `express.static` que usabas para servir el swagger terminando eso lo importas y despues puedes servirlo con la instruccion `app.use(router)`